OAuth2 Integration with Binance
I am reaching out regarding an issue we are facing while trying to implement OAuth2 with Binance. Our platform supports multiple environments: web, desktop, and mobile applications.
While OAuth works perfectly for our web application, we are encountering issues with the desktop and mobile app versions. Here are the details of the approaches we’ve tried:

Desktop Application

We use redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/... as it’s the only feasible way to handle the callback for a desktop app since Binance redirects require a listener, and listening locally can only be done on http://localhost.
The problem is that localhost seems to be blocked (possibly due to a Cloudflare WAF rule), resulting in the request being denied.

Alternative Approach

As specified in Binance's documentation, we attempted to use redirect_uri=app://eflows.com
However, this results in another error:
HTTP 400 (Bad Request) Invalid_Request OAuth 2.0 Parameter: redirect_uri
So, we are looking for a solution, but right now I can't find any way to solve this. Any idea is welcome.
